# Is there a way to tell whether StorageArea.remove actually removed something?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to know whether a call to [`StorageArea.remove`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-remove) actually removed something (and if it did, how many items)?

The documentation doesn't seem to say anything about it, and I'm hoping there is some way to do that that doesn't require calling `get` first to check whether something is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you can see from the docs, the callback has no parameters - no, nothing is reported, except for errors through an API variable.

The route with `get` first is the right one.

Semantically, `remove` is "make sure those elements aren't there". That's exactly what it does.